# Glassfish4 execution errors

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I have a brand new installation of glassfish4. I added one glassfish server to my list of servers in Eclipse kepler.
I now get the error `Unable to start server on time. java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`. In the stack trace, I 
see `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`. I googled the first message and tried to fix it by removing
the osgi folder and replacing a glassfish jar as mentioned here - [Unable to find or serve resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834040/unable-to-find-or-serve-resource)
That gave me a new error which said something like antivirus or something else is blocking glassfish. I googled the second
message and got one link which did not help - [How do I clear an address for Glassfish 4.0 with default settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317527/how-do-i-clear-an-address-for-glassfish-4-0-with-default-settings)

Finally, I decided to reinstall glassfish4 and try all over again. I get the same error messages again. Now, I don't know what to do. Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Please do not edit your answer into the question.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - the question is clear and i want to answer it. SO now allows me to answer my own questions.